# how can I center the view horizontally in vim while still wrapping at 100 characters?

Tags: vim, tmux, iterm2

here is what it would ideally look like: [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZh3M.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewugC.png)

I tried [DistractFree](https://github.com/vim-scripts/DistractFree) but even ignoring the errors I get, it doesn't center and adds '|' columns etc.

I tried [this gist](https://gist.github.com/amacdougall/1989803) too but it results in a very narrow column and also with '|' columns.

[vimroom](https://github.com/mikewest/vimroom/blob/master/plugin/vimroom.vim) gets closer to what I want it to look like but apart from the extra characters it's still using the mutli-window/panes method that means I have to `:q` three times to leave.

I'm on macOS with iTerm, I'm also willing to use tmux (but would be much better if I don't need to).

thanks a lot

Comment: DistractFree author here: what kind of errors did you get? And what did you expect?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I tried it again and got those: https://gist.github.com/localhostdotdev/43ea0530dbe09d4edb655e2a1b4865f8 (BTW `:q` works fine on your plugin). here is what I get: https://i.imgur.com/91PTjKa.png (I would need to find a way to wrap to 100 characters, remove the top/bottom margins and the '|' and '~' characters)

Comment: Never use the vim-scripts mirror, that is outdated. Use my plugin directly: https://github.com/chrisbra/DistractFree I have never seen that error. What Vim version is this? For setting the window-size, read the help `:h DistractFree-size`

Answer (score 0):

of course right after I post the question I find the solution:

https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim

[with goyo default options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDSAp.png)